# Capture Line numbers of lines matching a search

Tags: search, vim, pattern-matching, match, lines

Example:

search:

```
/lastword\s*\n\zs\(\s*\n\)\{6}\ze\s*startword
```

This search searches 6 empty lines between a line ending with "lastword" and a line starting with "startword"

I would like to catch the linenumbers of the empty lines matching this search.

Is there a way to do this in vim?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `:g` and `:number` (or `:#` for short) to print out the lines with line numbers.

```
:g/lastword\s*\n\zs\(\s*\n\)\{6}\ze\s*startword/#
```

To capture this content you have to use `:redir` to redirect the output to somewhere else. In this case below we redirect it to the unamed register (`@"`)

```
:redir @"|execute 'g/pattern/#'|redir END
```

Note: Must use `:execute` with `:g` otherwise `redir END` will be executed on each matching line with the `:g` command.

Now as it is this is going to print via `:#` the starting line which is not what we want (we want the empty lines between `foo` and `bar`). We can use a range with the `:#` command to accomplish this.

```
:redir @"|execute 'g/foo\_.*bar/+,/bar/-#'|redir END
```

The range is now `+,/bar/-` which translate to start the next line (`+`) and the search for `bar` (`/bar/`) then subtract one line (`-`). We can probably simplify this some as we know the number of empty lines should be 6.

```
:redir @"|execute 'g/foo\_.*bar/+#6'|redir END
```

We can take this further by putting the content into a new buffer and remove the extra lines.

```
:redir @"|exe 'g/pattern/+#6'|redir END|new|pu|%s/\d\+\zs.*//|%le|g/^$/d
```

There is a lot going on here, but the idea is we capture the output, open a new buffer, paste the content, and then clean up the output.

#### Alternative

Alternatively awk might make this a bit easier. Run the following on the current Vim buffer:

```
:%!awk '/lastword\s*$/,/^\s*startword/ { if($0 ~ /^\s*$/) { print NR} }'
```

For more help see:

```
:h :g
:h :redir
:h :exe
:h :range
:h :new
:h :pu
:h /\zs
:h :le
:h :d
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. I noted that this captures the line before the empty lines, not the empty lines. Is this because of `\zs`?

Comment: @Reman, you are correct. I forgot to add the range portion. The `\zs` and `\ze` are less helpful. What we need is to use a range and a count for `:#`. The `:g` command would be more like the following. `:g/pattern/+#6`. I have updated the post

Comment: Wow :) Great solution. There is only one thing I still don't know. I just tried with another search "find empty lines between pattern": `/lastword\s*\n\zs\(\s*\n\)\{2,4}\ze\s*startword` How do I resolve this with the parameter {2,4}? I also have double searches like this `/lastword\s*\n\zs\(\s*\n\)\{2,4}\ze\s*startword\|/lastword\s*\n\zs\(\s*\n\)\{6}\ze\s*startword`

Comment: I gave the solution when I talked about ranges. basically instead of specifying a fixed number you use a search as the end of the range for the `:#` command. e.g. `:redir @"|exe 'g/lastword\s*\n\zs\(\s*\n\)\{2,4}\ze\s*startword\|/lastword\s‌​*\n\zs\(\s*\n\)\{6}\‌​ze\s*startword/+,/^\s*startword/-#'|redir END|new|pu|%s/\d\+\zs.*//|%le|g/^$/d`

Comment: Indeed, the AWK solution is even easier. This prints the lines in a new buffer. Do you know how to print the lines to a register (or clipboard) and not to a new buffer?